# Weird encoding issue in Orchard web pages

Tags: unicode, encoding, utf-8, orchardcms, projection

Lately, I got a really weird bug that it’s even hard to describe. We have a site created with Orchard in 2 servers, the dev server and the production-live server. In the dev server everything works perfectly. In the production server, if you are logged on the CMS, again everything works well. If you are not logged on though, like the actual visitors of the site are, then it’s nearly perfect. The problem is almost random and happens only in 1-2 places in the whole site (different places). There, the browser fails with the encoding of probably a single char and displays instead 2 question marks inside a rhomboid shape. I found a really great article about Unicode and UTF8 http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/06/06/all-about-unicode-utf8-character-sets/ and from what I got from there, UTF8 in the browser fails to make sense of the numbers of a single char encoded in a different charset.

What I struggle to gasp is why we get the problem only in a couple of places, which don’t seem to have a connection whatsoever? Why on the one server and not on the other (both sites are set up identically)? Why it doesn’t happen when you are logged onthe CMS? And why they happen in random places that even change if we reload a problematic page. I mean the computers are not humans, who might translate and write something wrongly at a random time by mistake. They will either get it right or wrong. In this case the browser it displays almost everything right, apart form 1-2 characters (among thousands of other similar characters) in random pages. We managed to constrain the problem to the text inside the slides of projection widgets.

It looks like a problem of orchard and/or projection widget. It’s a really weird one, but I would appreciate any help or direction and especially any reasonable explanation of how something like that can occur.

Comment: I’m afraid the problem is impossible to analyze without some hard facts. If you can take a snapshot of a page where the problem appears and store it under a permanent URL and include the URL and an identification of the location of the error there, then we could at least see what the problem is (including what specific data there is on the page). The real cause might still be in the CMS and thus not analyzable from outside.

Comment: The text “UTF8 in the browser fails to make sense of the numbers of a single char encoded in a different charset” in the question suggests that you are trying to use data in two different character encodings in the same HTML document. That is not going to work. The data to be inserted into a document needs to be converted to the encoding used on and declared for the page.

Comment: Jukka thanks for replying. It's UTF8 through the whole page and site.

Comment: Where exactly are you getting these weird issues? If it is the projection widget, what is the query you are using :)

Comment: Hazza now is everywhere. I was doing some changes, enabled and disabled the combinator and now it got worse.