# Orchard 1.9 creates gibberish code output after deployment

Tags: iis, orchardcms

I have just started using Orchard 1.9. I come up with a big issue which I have never encountered when I used Orchard 1.8.x.

The new version gives out gibberish code after the site is deployed to a remote server. It works fine on local server. 
[image]
I am sure it's not an encoding issue, because after I switch the encoding to UTF-8, it creates a different set of gibberish.
[image]

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Could you please give us more insight on server specs and the app you are dealing with? What is the supposed output, where does it come from etc.? "Gibberish" by itself is meaningless - basic homework done with some finer details would be much appreciated.

Comment: I am using SmarterASP. The hosting environment is .NET 4.x(I). I don't know what else I can check. I don't either know where it comes from

Comment: The deployed site is: http://loksum-animalshelter.org. You may probably able to open the page at the first visit. When you click refresh button, the gibberish comes out.

Comment: I think I am having the same issue with this guy http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17420879/weird-encoding-issue-in-orchard-web-pages

Comment: What modules have you enabled/installed? Are there any errors in logs?

Comment: It appears there is problem with output cache module as jibberish is only coming out when page is cached. Disabling it should fix the problem for the time being.

Comment: Xeevis, Thanks a lot! You found the culprit. After the cache is set to 0, the problem is gone. Is there any way I can cache to improve the speed now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a theory that there is something strange going on with Output Cache combined with content encoding on your deployment server resulting in content perhaps being encoded twice?

With Output Cache turned back on try adding this line in your root `web.config` right before `</system.webServer>`

```
    <urlCompression doDynamicCompression="false" doStaticCompression="true" /> 
</system.webServer>
```

Does that help anything?

**Edit:**

You can try enabling dynamic compression and adding `dynamicCompressionBeforeCache` attribute with `false`, it's a default value but hosting may have changed it in their configs.

```
<urlCompression doDynamicCompression="true" doStaticCompression="true" dynamicCompressionBeforeCache="false" />
```

Comment: The cause is that IIS compresses output before Output Cache picks it up so it has compressed output cached and then when cached item is served IIS compresses it once again. This shouldn't be happening by default, it's possible your hosting changed a few settings. Please see the edit in the answer, it may resolve your issue without disabling the dynamic compression.

Comment: It's true. My HTTP Compress on my hosting panel is set to ON!